# iphone - Can't format label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, label

I can't format a label, here's my code:

```
ct.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", currentTimeMin, currentTime];
```

so ct is the label and it won't display the value.

ct in the .h file: `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *ct;`

I used `(strong, nonatomic)` as well but that didn't change anything

currentTimeMin is set to 0 and currentTime to `self.audioPlayer.currentTime` I think the problem could be there.

I have also tried to put `ct.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hey"];` didn't work either

Please help me! I am getting so sick of this. Thanks!

**EDIT**

And a weird thing is that I set up a label in another ViewController and then it worked but it's just in that single view that it won't work. Somehow, someway.

Comment: Do you use Interface Builder? If so, have you connected the label to the appropriate place?

Comment: Yes. The label is properly connected from the storyboard to the .h file.

Comment: After knowing that label is properly connected, the only possibility I can think of is that may be your text color and background color have been set to the same color and you are therefore unable to see the text!! You may laugh but it has happened with me :D

Comment: Try the simplest case: ct.text=@"test" ... what is the result of NSLog("ct.text = %@",ct.text) after you have set it...

Comment: @Atif Hahahah, can happen to everybody. Altough that's not my case since my label is black and background white ;)

Comment: @HeWas It returns with ct.text = (null) so it is not getting any data

Comment: If `ct.text= @"test"; NSLog(@"ct.text = %@", ct.text);` prints `ct.text = (null)` it can only mean that `ct` is *nil*. So it's not properly wired up in interface builder or the ViewController isn't correctly created.

Comment: As I said, check `NSLog("ct: %@",ct)` ... if you get nil (or null) that will confirm @Codo...

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comments and tests...

Either
(1) You are not referring to the label correctly. It should be self.ct

Or
(2) You have not wired up the label correctly. Please check it again. If you mean to assign content to a label.text but have not connected it to the property you will get a null result (as far as the program is concerned you have not alloc/init'ed the property).

Comment: Okay so now i did [[NSString alloc] init] in viewdidload but that didn't change the ct.text from being nothing. Altough it did set the label to null when i built and ran. So now instead of saying just "Label" it says nothing. Guess that's a start :)

Comment: what do you get from `NSLog("ct: %@",ct)`?